# Need to reload current_cart to get the test passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing my online store app with RSpec, here's what I'm doing:

```
# spec/controllers/line_items_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe LineItemsController do

  describe "POST 'create'" do
    before do
      @current_cart = Factory(:cart)
      controller.stub!(:current_cart).and_return(@current_cart)
    end

    it 'should merge two same line_items into one' do
      @product = Factory(:product, :name => "Tee")
      post 'create', {:product_id => @product.id}
      post 'create', {:product_id => @product.id}

      assert LineItem.count.should == 1
      assert LineItem.first.quantity.should == 2
    end
  end    
end

# app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create        
    current_cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
      if line_item.product_id == params[:product_id]
        line_item.quantity += 1
        if line_item.save
          render :text => "success"
        else
          render :text => "failed"
        end
        return
      end
    end

    @line_item = current_cart.line_items.new(:product_id => params[:product_id])

    if @line_item.save
      render :text => "success"
    else
      render :text => "failed"
    end
  end
end
```

The problem right now is it never added up two line_items having the same product into one, because the second time I entered into the `line_items_controller#create`, the `current_cart.line_items` is [], I have run `current_cart.reload` to get the test passed, any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that because you have stubbed out the controller's current_cart it's always returning `Factory(:cart)` which has no line_items.

If you're testing current_cart itself maybe it's best not to stub it out.

Also, is the `@line_item.save` call returning true?

Comment: I commented out the stub, and it doesn't work neither. `@line_item.save` returns true

Comment: @leomayleomay where are the inital current_cart.line_items set up?

Comment: cart has_many line_items, I think that's where the initial current_cart.line_items setup

Comment: I may not be following this right, so apologies in advance. So it works if you call `current_cart.reload` in the action? If so current_cart is probably being cached between requests, which is normal. You could reload in the test between calls to `post`. Otherwise maybe split into separate tests. Create a `LineItem` within the spec and then call post once to test what happens when the second `LineItem` comes in.